# Equivalent of 'window' load event for child DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using this event to create a DataTable widget

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    TableData = $('#tableData').DataTable();
});
```

This works fine and also prevents the widget to be created before the images in the table cells are done loading (otherwise, the headers aren't aligned properly with the table columns).

But I'm having this problem where I update a single row in the table and sometimes, the images displayed in the cells are different so obviously there's a loading delay.

I think I need to call `TableData.draw()` only when the images are fully loaded but `$(window).on('load')` doesn't work anymore in this case because the window isn't actually loading.

This is what I do when updating a single row:

```
//temp has the data, tableRow[0] is the actually <tr> element.
$('#tableData').dataTable().fnUpdate(temp, tableRow[0], null, true, true);
```

How would I detect images done loading in this case ? I've tried

```
$(tableRow[0]).load('url', function (e) { //logic... })
```

But this is executing once `url` returns the data, not after images are done loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use the `load` event of the images in the same way you would with `window`.

Comment: You can use `$(selector for image).on("load", ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images support a `load` event that works in much the same way that it works with `window`.

```js
// Pure JS:
document.querySelector("#one").addEventListener("load", function(){ alert("Image One Loaded!"); });

// JQuery:
$("#two").on("load", function(){ alert("Image Two Loaded!"); });
```

```css
img { width:100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="one" src="http://laoblogger.com/images/image-of-smiley-face-6.jpg">
<img id="two" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/smiley-face-thumbs-up-thank-you-10_smiley_face.jpg">
```

To check if all images in a cell have been loaded, you can do this:

```js
// Get a all the images in the cell of the table and put them into an array
var imgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("table td > img"));

var count = 0; // Keeps track of how many images are loaded 

// Loop over each image...
imgs.forEach(function(img){
  // Set up load event handler
  img.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // Increase the count and check to see if all images in cell are loaded
    var msg = "";
    if(++count === imgs.length){ 
      msg= "All images in cell are loaded!";
    } else {
      msg = count + " images have loaded.";
    }
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

```css
img { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img id="one" src="http://laoblogger.com/images/image-of-smiley-face-6.jpg">
      <img id="two" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/smiley-face-thumbs-up-thank-you-10_smiley_face.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I could indeed use the load event of single images, the issue here is that I don't know exactly how many of them there are inside a cell. That's why I was looking for an event on a parent holding all these images. The table row itself doesn't have such an event apparently.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme You would just query for all the images in the cell and set each up with a `.load` event handler. Then you would maintain a counter that increments in each of those handlers and checks to see if the count is equal to the `.length` of the node list of all the images in the cell that you got in the first place.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme I have updated the answer to show this.

Comment: I ended up using something like this. But the issue what that once the `src` attribute is set, attaching an handler won't work. A hack is to, once the document is ready, set the `src` of each to its original value, and the events are triggered.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Well, you can attach a handler at any time as long as the line that attaches the handler is processed before the `load` event of the `img` has fired, otherwise, you'll miss it.